# Cancel a user task when another user task is completed

Tags: activiti, bpmn

Two user tasks (task A and B) are created in parallel, and when one task is completed need to cancel the other vice versa. This can be done with the use of a task listener (event on complete). However the issue is if both tasks are completed at the same time how to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried that out? Competing a task is a transactional operation, that means that if both tasks are completed at the same time only one transaction will “win” and the other will be rolled-back pushing the second transaction to be retried. In general that should work if you have that retrying mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a userTask with `multiple instances`. It can create multiple usertasks at the same time and set different conditions to end the multiple instances.

here is the syntax rules

```
<userTask id="userTask1" name="Activiti is awesome!" activiti:assignee="${user}">
    <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" activiti:collection="${userList}" activiti:elementVariable="user">
        <completionCondition>${nrOfCompletedInstances == nrOfInstances}</completionCondition>
    </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
</userTask>
```

- IsSequential means parallel or serial creation
- ${userList} means a list object received from the outside
- completionCondition means that all outstanding userTask will be automatically deleted once the conditions you set are met.

More information can be found at [activiti User Guide#Multi-instance](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnMultiInstance)

Hope that can solve your problem!